# How can I set my $_SESSION?

Tags: php, session

So I have this problem because I always got the undefined index in my session. Here is my code below:

```
    session_start();

if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $pass_hash = md5($password);

        if (!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$pass_hash'";
            $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run);
                if ($row['user_type'] == 'admin') {
                    $_SESSION['username'] == $username;
                    echo $_SESSION['username'];
                }
```

I'm trying to echo out the $_SESSION['username'] but i always got an undefined index error

Comment: Please provide the exact error message with the line number and corresponding line in the code.

Comment: Undefined index: username in line 15 and 16. Line 15 and 16 is
                        $_SESSION['username'] == $username;
                    echo $_SESSION['username'];
by the way, thanks for your help. i already know the reason why i get the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using double equal which is for comparing and result of it is boolean.

`$_SESSION['username'] == $username;` replace those `==` with just one `=`. I bet this is just a typo in Your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change.

```
  $_SESSION['username'] == $username;
```

to

```
  $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```